# Uninstalled PHP and php -v always returns 7.1.4

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, php-cli

I have installed php from ondrej. I followed many answers about removing it. However, the apache does not able load php but everytime I try to use `php -v` from the terminal it returns :

> PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: May  9 2017 21:55:10) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017
>   Zend Technologies

Comment: Have you removed the ondrej PPA from your apt lists?

Comment: Yes using purge

Comment: Purge only removes the packages and configs, did you actually remove the repos from /etc/apt/?  After you remove them there, then you need to update `apt-get install update` and then reinstall `apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version Apache uses and the PHP version the command `php -v` uses are two different things.

To use a specific CLI version of PHP, you have to install the `php-cli` package. After you install it, use `update-alternatives` to tell the `php` which version to use.

For example if you want to use `php8.1-cli`, do this:

```
sudo apt install php8.1-cli

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. You have to `sudo apt-get purge php*`.

Comment: Can you do this for a specific version of php? I used sudo apt-het purge php7.3 and it said it uninstalled but when I ran php -v it is still showing php7.3 instead of php7.4